# Simulate a data frame with different sequence per column

Tags: r, dataframe, simulation

I would like to simulate in R a data frame with 4 columns with the above conditions:

1. Each row is summing up to 1
2. The first element of column 1 starts with being closer to 1, say 0.9, but gradually decreases per row.
3. The elements of the other 3 columns start low, say something between 0.02 - 0.05, but gradually increase with each row.
4. I would like the last row of the data frame being c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25).

Can you help me with creating something like that ?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO, What have you tried so far, what are the coding problems you have faced?

Comment: I am thinking of how to initialize it, should I start column-wise or row-wise ? In addition, I understand since I would like the last row to be specified, the dimensions of the matrix would be fixed. Do you have any recommendations or hints on how to approach this with some code, I am quite new to this.

Comment: There is so much which is unstated: how many rows? are the elements to be random or  sequential (column wise)?

Comment: Let's say 1000 rows. Column wise it does not matter in the end, whatever is computationally easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# State the number of rows you want to create
rows <- 1000

# Create 4 randomly generated columns, the first ranging [.25, 1], the others [0, .25] and add .25 as the last row
x1<-c(runif(rows-1,.25,1), .25)
x2<-c(runif(rows-1,0,.25), .25)
x3<-c(runif(rows-1,0,.25), .25)
x4<-c(runif(rows-1,0,.25), .25)

library(dplyr)
# Combine the columns into a single table
df <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4)

df %>% 
  # Sort each column individually (meaning the sorting of 1 column doesn't affect another)
  mutate(x1 = sort(x1, decreasing = T)) %>%
  mutate(across(x2:x4, ~sort(.x))) %>%
  # Transpose the table so you can sort the rows
  t() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate_all(.funs = ~sort(., decreasing = T)) %>%
  t() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  # Scale the table you have so the sum of each row equals to 1
  mutate_all(.funs = ~ ./rowSums(across(everything())))
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @PurpleKoala if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.